# Prove $\theta$ is an increasing function of $\lambda$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> For the following equation prove that $\theta(1,\lambda)$ is an increasing function of $\lambda$. It is just as easy to prove that $\theta(1,\lambda)$ is an increasing function of $\lambda$ for every fixed $x$ in $0< x\leq 1$. All we have to prove is that $\theta(1,\lambda)$ is a continuous function of $\lambda$ which approaches infinity as $\lambda$ approaches infinity. These facts are almost obvious from the d.e. since $r$ is positive on $[0,1]$. A slight problem is that $\sin^2 \theta$ is not bounded away from zero. $$(p(x)y')'-q(x)y+\lambda r(x)y=0
> $$$$y=\rho \sin \theta,    p y'=\rho \cos \theta$$

$$\theta'=\frac{1}{p}\cos ^2\theta+(\lambda r-q)\sin ^2 \theta$$

> Boundary conditions are
>   $$a_1y(0)+a_2y'(0)=0$$$$ b_1y(1)+b_2y'(1)=0$$
>   Initial conditions are:
>   $$a_1\sin\theta(0)+\frac{a_2}{p(0)}\cos\theta(0)=0$$$$0\leq \theta(0)< \pi$$

$$\tan \theta(1,\lambda)=\frac{-b_2}{b_1p(1)}$$

> What are the technical details necessary to complete this argument?

Comment: What are $b_1$ and $b_2$?  Are $p$, $q$ , and $r$ functions of $x$?

Comment: $(p(x)y')'-q(x)y+\lambda r(x)y=0$,   $y=\rho \sin \theta,    p y'=\rho \cos \theta$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, both in comment and question. 